# what is the use of param in Hibernate <generator> tag?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and in my current project hibernate config file,I found some codes like below:

```
<id name="id" column="ANNOBATCHJOBLOGID">
    <generator class="sg.gov.frontier.core.techinfra.persistence.dao.SequenceGeneratorYYYYMMDD">
        <param name="sequence">ANNO_BATCH_JOB_LOG_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

just feel confused about the the param tag ,can someone tell me what is the use of it? and also the "ANNO_BATCH_JOB_LOG_SEQ" .Thanks a lot

the SequenceGeneratorYYYYMMDD class is here :

```
public class SequenceGeneratorYYYYMMDD extends SequenceGenerator {
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SequenceGeneratorYYYYMMDD.class);
    public String sequenceName;
    public String parameters;

    public static final long SEQUENCE_MIN_NUMBER = 1;
    public static final long SEQUENCE_MAX_NUMBER = 999999;
    public static final long SEQUENCE_INCREMENT_NUMBER = 1;
    public static final long SEQUENCE_START_NUMBER = 1;

    public SequenceGeneratorYYYYMMDD() {
        super();
    }

    public long getNextSequenceForSequenceName(String strSequenceName)
            throws DataAccessObjectException {
        final SequenceDao sequenceDao = new SequenceDao();

        Long sequence = sequenceDao.getNextKey(strSequenceName);

        return sequence;
    }

    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect)
            throws MappingException {
        this.sequenceName = getString(SEQUENCE, params, "hibernate_sequence");
        this.parameters = params.getProperty(PARAMETERS);
        String schemaName = params.getProperty(SCHEMA);
        String catalogName = params.getProperty(CATALOG);

        if (sequenceName.indexOf('.') < 0) {
            sequenceName = Table.qualify(catalogName, schemaName, sequenceName);
        }

    }

    public String getString(String property, Properties properties,
            String defaultValue) {
        String propValue = properties.getProperty(property);
        return propValue == null ? defaultValue : propValue;
    }

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj)
            throws HibernateException {

        String result = DateUtil.convertDateToDateString(new DateTime(),
                "yyMMddHH");

        try {
            result = result
                    + StringUtil
                            .leftPad(
                                    String.valueOf(getNextSequenceForSequenceName(sequenceName)),
                                    '0', 8);
        } catch (DataAccessObjectException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }

        logger.debug("Generated sequence no. " + result);
        return new Long(result);

    }
}
```

how can i know which method i need to pass the param? though seems is getNextSequenceForSequenceName() method.

Comment: Let's see your `SequenceGeneratorYYYYMMDD` class.

Comment: yeah looks like a sequence, sorry im being obvious, but something cool i found was some annotations you can control related to this. Google sequences in hibernate to find them. I think the param is telling the program that ANNO_BATCH_JOB_LOG_SEQ is a sequence. Being placed with the generator tag as a parent probably tells hibernate to use that sequence with the generator. Do you think its related to logging of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Hibernate docs 5.1.4.1. Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)

> The optional `<generator>` child element names a Java class used to generate unique identifiers for instances of the persistent class. **If any parameters are required to configure or initialize the generator instance, they are passed using the `<param>` element.**

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="cat_id">
    <generator class="org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator">
            <param name="table">uid_table</param>
            <param name="column">next_hi_value_column</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Comment: but there are multiple methods in my generator class . how could i know which method i need to pass the value?